# Alternating sum

Tags: summation

A frog is at the bottom of a 30 metre well. Each day it climbs 5 metres up the side, but it then slips back 3 metres each night. How long does it take to reach the top of the well?

Is there an easier /more direct way to make an alternating sum than this?

```
y = 14; Flatten[Transpose[{Table[2 x + 5, {x, 0, y - 1}], 
Table[2 x, {x, 1, y}]}]]
```

## Update

Not automated, but simple and more direct than first attempt:

```
Accumulate[Table[If[OddQ[n], 5, -3], {n, 1, 27}]]
```

Comment: This problem will make some of our most active users very happy, +1.

Comment: If you're just looking for a compact and efficient way to get the partial sum list (per your update), `Array[2-2(-1)^#+#&,27]` is the way to go...

Comment: The result is `(well depth / meters climbed) / (meters climbed - meters slipped)` rounded up and added one: `Ceiling[(30 - 5)/(5 - 3)] + 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure whether this is simpler, but it more directly follows the problem, and you don't have to compute the number of iterations in advance:

```
Rest[
   NestWhileList[{First@# + If[EvenQ[Last@#], 5, -3], Last@# + 1} &, {0, 0}, First@# < 30 &]
][[All, 1]]

(* 
    {5, 2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8, 13, 10, 15, 12, 17, 14, 19, 16, 21, 
      18, 23, 20, 25, 22, 27, 24, 29, 26, 31} 
*)
```

Here, each iteration produces a list of two elements, where the first one is the total distance climbed so far, and the last one is simply the number of the step. When the top is reached, iteration stops.

A more readable form of this code would be:

```
ClearAll[nextStep];
nextStep[{distance_, index_?EvenQ}] := {distance + 5, index + 1};
nextStep[{distance_, index_?OddQ}] := {distance - 3, index + 1};
```

and then

```
Rest[NestWhileList[nextStep, {0, 0}, First@# < 30 &]][[All, 1]]
```

Comment: A nice solution :) Still trying to get to grips with `@` and `#` - think this simple code may help me on my way. Also, I think `NestWhileList` is what I was probably searching for here :)

Comment: @martin Well, you can use `Last[#], First[#]`, etc, instead of the prefix form, if it is more readable for you - the user of `@` is a purely stylistic matter.

Comment: I see that `[[All]]` is short form of `Part` too :)

Comment: @martin Well, `[[All,index]]` is a compact and fast way to extract a given column from a nested list. See also my edit for a more readable version of this code.

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun and a little ugly:

```
f[x_, c_] := {x + (3 + 2 Mod[c, 2]) (-1)^(Mod[c, 2] + 1), c + 1}
ans = NestWhileList[f @@ # &, {-30, 1}, First@# < 0 &];
```

The number of steps is `Length@ans-1`.
Visualizing:

[image]

This was animated gif made from:

```
{pos, steps} = Transpose[ans];
anim = MapThread[
   ListPlot[pos[[1 ;; #1]], Epilog -> Inset[Framed[#2], {5, -10}], 
     PlotRange -> {{0, Length@pos + 1}, {-35, 2}}, Joined -> True, 
     ImageSize -> 300, BaseStyle -> 20] &, {Range[2, Length@pos], 
    Most@steps}];
```

Answer (score 8):

Using a recurrence equation :-

```
height = -30;
slip = 3;
climb = 5;

sol = RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] - slip + climb,
   a[0] == height + slip}, a, n]
```

> {{a -> Function[{n}, -27 + 2 n]}}

```
f = First[a /. sol];
n = 0; While[f[n] < 0, ++n]
Print["Frog reaches the top on day ", n]
```

> Frog reaches the top on day 14

Comment: neat and the answers with days not steps +1 :)

Comment: It looks pedestrian, but this is a very readable solution. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
froggy[wellHeight_Integer] := Switch[EvenQ[wellHeight], True, wellHeight - 3, False, 
  wellHeight - 4];

(* 30 Meter well *)
froggy[30]

(* 27 *)
```

I will wager this is the highest performing solution ;-}

An actual tailorable method:

```
up = 5;
down = 3;
height = 30;
moves = 0;

While[Sum[Boole[OddQ[x]] up - Boole[EvenQ[x]] down, {x, 1, moves}] <height, moves++];

moves

(* 27 *)
```

A neat and concise way to get the steps is via a linear recurrence (indexed to zero move):

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 1, -1}, {0, 5, 2}, 28]

(* {0, 5, 2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8, 13, 10, 15, 12, 17, 14, 19, 16, 21, 18, 23, 20,
    25, 22, 27, 24, 29, 26, 31} *)
```

Comment: A very concise solution! Struggling with `Switch` though ... where does the `-4` come from?

Comment: @martin: I am just goofing with *L.S.* et al, the constants are derived from your particular example, so if height is even integer, it takes *heght-3* moves, if odd, *height-4* moves. I'll add a "real" alternative that is responsive to the question.

Comment: @martin: syntax & semantics of `Switch` can be found in the docs: basically, do a test (the `EvenQ` part in my case), followed with a series of value pairs, first that matches test result means next is the result value. 
Also, note the site you're on: any frog here is smart enough to wait for some heavy rain and float out sans any effort :P

Answer (score 3):

Quite obviously the frog will reach the top while on a 5-meter-up move. It is the easier to assume that it *first* goes down 3 meters and *then* up 5 meters, for a total of 2 meters up.

Now, starting from -30, go up 5 to -25 (day 1) and then repeat the above (-3+5=2) steps. The number of days is thus

$1+\lceil 25/2 \rceil = 14$

(sorry, no Mathematica!)

Comment: Why floor? $13\frac{1}{2}$ is correct (so reaches the top on the 14th day).

Comment: @Martin you are correct, error fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just in the spirit of fun I post this as another: just a variant.

```
res=NestWhileList[Function[{x,j},{1+4 Cos[Pi j]+ x,j+1}]@@#&,{-30,0},First@#<0&]
```

As before the number of steps is `Length@res-1` and number of days `Ceiling[Length@res/2-1/2]`.

Comment: Nice - shows step numbers! :)